# Per machine variables in ExtJS 7

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs7

I am developing an app using ExtJS 7 and have a team of developers.

Each user is getting their external API's from a different source, i.e some `localhost`, some `192.168.1.100` etc etc

Is it possible to write something like an `env` file that each developer can add to their directory root and then I can pull in a variable into the app?

There is a way in pretty much every other system these days, but it seems Ext doesnt do this apart from hardcoding the value into the `app.json` but as this is committed to source control, it gets really messy

Something simple like

```
API_URL=https://localhost/api
```

If anyone has developed something like this, could they please share, I haven't been able to find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let them setup a common local development host-name, either in `/etc/hosts` or `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`. This file is being queried, before any DNS server will be queried - so it could even be the host-name of the public API, which still would resolve locally.

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
# 127.0.0.1   api.local
192.168.1.100 api.local
```

Comment: Hey @Martin ... I would rather not go this route. as it means editing an system file. I would rather a file in the root of the project, and have Ext pull in that variable

Comment: @CodeSauce This is absurd, because there are no additional config files and JavaScript could not care less, DNS is all that matters - and it is quite common to do this.

Comment: It is? .. I feel that the hosts option is absurd

Comment: Good luck with finding any better, more reliable & portable solution. Without a host-name (IP only), the web-server can only serve the default virtual host, since the request has no host-header... and alike this, the request has one. This has absolutely nothing to do with `extjs` or `sencha-cmd`, but strictly `dns`. So how about adding another one project's API to the same web-server, how would you do that?

Comment: Fair play. Looks like this is what im going to go with. Thanks for your response.

Comment: DNS is always being provided externally - even with local resolution, it still behaves alike that.